# hasOwnProperty is traversing the prototype chain

Tags: javascript

Today I noticed some weird behavior of `hasOwnProperty` method.

I'm on environments that fully support ES6 classes, so there is no transpilation to worry about.

The above code snippet should be returning true and false respectively, but it returns true on both.

```js
class Stuff {
  constructor() { this.something = 'something'; }
}
class MoreStuff extends Stuff {}
const stuff = new Stuff();
const moreStuff = new MoreStuff();

console.log(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(stuff, 'something'));
console.log(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(moreStuff, 'something'));
```

Maybe I'm missing something here, but as long as I know, something exists on stuff and it is inherited on moreStuff, but seems that it exist on both.
What I am missing?

Comment: Why are you using `call`? `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` is normally invoked on the class, not the instance.

Comment: @evolutionxbox no, backwards; it's called on the instance, as in `stuff.hasOwnProperty("something")`

Comment: @Pointy thanks for clarifying. Is there any case where you would use `call` with `hasOwnProperty`?

Comment: Well I can't think of a reason to do so off the top of my head. I can't say definitively that it *never* would make sense, but generally the situation involves an object reference so it's just as easy to use it directly.

Comment: There are several situations where you can not rely on an object having that method. `Object.create(null)`, `undefined` or `null` are examples of things that will throw if you try to call that method directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When, in your contsructor, you do this:

```
this.something = 'something';
```

You are putting that value into the object and not into the prototype.

Even if you subclass, the constructor adds the value of `'something'` into the object.

If you want it on the prototype then it has to be made static:

```js
class Stuff {
  static get something() {
    return 'something';
  }
  
  constructor() {
    this.ownProp = true;
  }
}
Stuff.somethingElse = 'somethingElse';

class MoreStuff extends Stuff {}
const stuff = new Stuff();
const moreStuff = new MoreStuff();

console.log(stuff.hasOwnProperty('something'));
console.log(stuff.hasOwnProperty('somethingElse'));
console.log(stuff.hasOwnProperty('ownProp'));
console.log(moreStuff.hasOwnProperty('something'));
console.log(moreStuff.hasOwnProperty('somethingElse'));
console.log(moreStuff.hasOwnProperty('ownProp'));
```

`ownProp` is still a property of the instance where `something` and `somethingElse` are properties of the Class (Prototype)

Comment: So there is no way to add normal "properties" to a class that only belong to each instance. Everything that is added on the constructor is an instance prop. Only works for methods then. I'm not very worried about it, but it is good to know. Being a super fan of prototypical inheritance it is a shame that I didn't figured this out myself.

Comment: If you place your property as part of the class (A Static value) then it is available to all instances of the class.

Comment: I was not clear, sorry. I mean there is no way to make a property to be `ownProperty` on instances of a class but not being an own property on extended classes. Static properties always belong to the prototype, not the instance, which makes sense to be honest.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. Yes, you are correct. It is either `ownProperty` on the instance or `ownProperty` on the class definition. It can be both if the class has a static and then you also set a value on the instance, but I doubt that is what you want.

Answer (score 4):

The `Stuff` constructor puts the "something" property directly on the constructed object. That'll be true whether you're making an instance of the parent class or the inheriting class.  The prototype chain isn't involved.